# Display resultset from database using shell script every 4 seconds

Tags: oracle, bash, shell

I am attempting todisplay a resultset from oracle database every 4 second using shell script. This is what I have so far, but it gives me the oracle version information and unformated results:

```
#!/bin/bash
RETVAL=`sqlplus "username/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=HOSTNAME)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SIDNAME)))" <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 200 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
select user_id,user_work_class,sol_id,user_appl_name from upr where user_logged_on_flg = 'Y';
EXIT;
EOF`
if [ -z "$RETVAL" ]; then
  echo "No rows returned from database"
  exit 0
else
  echo $RETVAL
fi
```

Any ideas or direction will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the question about the "every 4 seconds" part or the script itself?

Comment: The display as well is distorted.

Comment: Please split the question into 2 questions and remove all the stuff that is relevant to you but not relevant to others.

Comment: I answered the part about the time interval. If you need help with the ouptut of the command then you should ask a separate question giving the incorrect output and the desired output. Please check my solution about the interval and see if that works for you.

Comment: Every time you run sqlplus, it gives you its own initial message and I believe you can not avoid that. One way to solve could be building a sql script that spools data to a file and then, in the OS part, check the content of that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query returns rows, you can only take what is after the space to test.
Make code:

```
$RETVAL_TST= `echo $RETVAL | awk '{print $2}'`

if [ -z "$RETVAL_TST" ]; then
  echo "No rows returned from database"
  exit 0
else
  echo $RETVAL
fi
```

but the column on which you test awk `'{print $2}'` must be a key and not empty.

Answer (score -1):

To run the script every 4 seconds, you need to set up a loop with `sleep`.
If the script is called `script.sh`:

```
for i in {1..100} ; do sh script.sh ; sleep 4 ; done > output
```

That will run the script 100 times with intervals of 4 seconds between each run and save the output into a file called `output`.

Edit-

If you want the script to run indefinitely then the `for` loop isn't a great idea. As mentioned by @Kacper, the `while` loop is better suited to that-

```
while(true) ; do sh script.sh ; sleep 4 ; done > output
```

Comment: If it is going to run every 4 seconds you probably need `while(true)` not `for`